# jQUERY get the parent folder of url

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to use Ajax to load an `xml` file. This file is located into another folder of the root directory.

1. How do I get the root directory path with `jQuery`?
2. How do I move to the parent directory of the current path with `jQuery`?

Comment: Welcome to SO.. Recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/ (Links are because looks that you'r mixing concepts, and it's a good start to know and understand what you're doing and do it well)

Comment: Load means? Are you copying this file to your server?

Comment: I don't want to move the file. I want to load the file which is one level up.

Comment: @ΛάζαροςΚώτσικας Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

This returns the root/hostname:

```
window.location.hostname
```

This returns the path of parent folder.

```
var string1 = "../example/index.html";
var string2 = string1.replace(string1.split("/").pop(),"");
```

> string2=../example/